# Failed to execute 'send' on 'XMLHttpRequest' for only one url in Loopback

Tags: xmlhttprequest, loopbackjs, strongloop

Strongloop/Loopback node.js server used with 'ng-admin' editor and sqlite db. I need to get count of entities:

```
  var Httpreq = new XMLHttpRequest();
  Httpreq.open('GET', yourUrl, false);
  Httpreq.send(null);
  return Httpreq.responseText;
```

where `yourUrl` is like `http://localhost:3000/api/v1/entity/count`.

All urls works except one of entity named 'Advertisement', I have `angular.js:12783 Error: Failed to execute 'send' on 'XMLHttpRequest': Failed to load http://localhost:3000/api/v1/advertisement/count`. This url works in API explorer.

Advertisement.json:

```
{
  "name": "Advertisement",
  "base": "EntityBase",
  "plural": "Advertisement",
  "options": {
    "validateUpsert": true,
    "sqlite3": {
      "table": "advertisement"
    }
  },
  "properties": {
    "name": {
      "type": "string",
      "required": true
    },
    "category_id": {
      "type": "number"
    },
    "due_date": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "from_date": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "phone": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "site": {
      "type": "string"
    }
  },
  "validations": [],
  "relations": {
    "category": {
      "type": "belongsTo",
      "model": "Category",
      "foreignKey": "category_id"
    },
    "photos": {
      "type": "hasMany",
      "model": "Photo",
      "foreignKey": "advertisement_id"
    }
  },
  "acls": [],
  "methods": {},
  "mixins": {
    "Timestamp": {},
    "SoftDelete": {},
    "GenderAge": {},
    "Descripted": {}
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you show Advertisement.json ?

Comment: Added. Note that there is entity with same json, only other names/table/photo fk.

Comment: You mean there is another model that extends EntityBase and shares pretty much the same json config ?

Comment: Also, can you take a screenshot of the explorer while calling that endpoint ?

Comment: Yes, there is another model. Screenshot: http://i.imgur.com/EcV8ESd.png (no responce from server)

Comment: No response from server means your server is simply not started. Are you sure you correctly started running `node .` ?

Comment: Of course, when I test other methods works. Just noticed, `Advertisement/id` does not work too.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114838/discussion-between-overdrivr-and-user3009578).

Answer (score 0):

Renamed entity to Commercial to fix this.